# WiX NeverOverwrite flag deletes file

Tags: wix

I have a data file that is installed with my application.  When it is installed fresh, the data file gets installed properly.  When it is upgrading, it was always overwriting the existing instance of the file, which was not wanted.  I added the NeverOverwrite="yes" flag, and now for a new install is still the same, but for an existing install, it is deleting the existing file, and not installing the new file either.  Have I used the flag incorrectly?  This is the snippet in question:

```
<Component Id="cmp8553E6DDC92DBCDC568FB76CA13E7AF2" Guid="{C94263EB-56AF-4B19-942F-C92998252932}" NeverOverwrite="yes">
    <File Id="fil7C9456E83E3FB4618684509DEEF67EBD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.CDWrapper.ProjectDir)..\foo\bar" />
</Component>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I didn't have a full understanding of the NeverOverwrite flag and our usage of it.  I will have to find a different method to preserve the existing file instead of always installing a new copy, but that's a whole different issue that should have reasonable answers elsewhere.